# Receiving Data when app is not running in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

I want to make a tracking app and I want to get location and send to server even when app is not working.

I use Firebase for silent notification but not working if app is not working.

Is this possible with Firebase or how can I send data for my tracking app

Comment: You will need to use significant location change monitoring to keep your app running.

Comment: Are you saying you want code to run (your app) when the code (your app) is not running? hmm.